# Google maps directions UI

Tags: google-maps, driving-directions, map-directions

Is it possible to duplicate Google Maps directions user interface such as [the example shown here](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Chapel+Hill,+NC/Burger+King,+1828+Rock+Quarry+Rd,+Raleigh,+NC+27610/@35.8263837,-78.975997,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x89acc31c216e7ea7:0x7f03bae00443e4cb!2m2!1d-79.0558445!2d35.9131996!1m5!1m1!1s0x89ac5fad3a2ddb49:0x3ec368fa6aebf586!2m2!1d-78.612915!2d35.7547005)

Meaning, is there an API that I can call to display the from and to address, the different modes of transportation icons etc. on my website the same way that Google does? Here is a pic of what I would like to have:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, By Using Google Maps API, Polylines and Google Direction API, you can use it easily.
For more documentation you can use : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/api-picker

Here You will get all api's and Description of API's.